# VBA - Open multiple files, copy data from files to mastersheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am opening many files in a folder and trying to copy data [from F10 to the end of column F (some rows may be blank) and from G10 to the end of column G (some rows may be blank)] from the files to one worksheet called "masterfile", in columns 2 and 3 respectively, under a header. I have been trying to research AdvancedFilter() and CopyRange() but cannot get it to work correctly. I am not experienced with VBA so I am having a hard time figuring out how to even correctly use them. Any advice?

This code currently opens each file in a folder, prints the name of each file to the first column of the masterfile, and prints the information in cell J1 of the opened file down the 4th column of the masterfile. Any advice is greatly appreciated. I've been stuck for a week.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    Set StartSht = ActiveSheet
    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 1

    'loop through directory file and print names
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
            'print file name to Column 1
            Workbooks.Open fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name
            Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
            'print TOOLING DATA SHEET(TDS): values to Column 2
            With WB
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                    StartSht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
                    With ws
                        .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i + 1, 4)
                    End With
                    i = i + 1
                'move to next file
                Next ws
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that you cannot copy the text from the opened sheets?

To find the last row, I like to use: `LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` which gives you the number of rows in use.

Then with that, you can do: `Range(cells(10, 6), cells(LastRow, 7)).copy` and paste it into your master sheet. (In this case columns = 6 & 7 for F & G)

This will copy all data, even the blank cells. If you do not want blanks, you can `Selection.PasteSpecial` with `SkipBlanks:True`